# Is there a graphic design software specifically for creating stick figures?

Tags: vector-graphics, graphic-design

For a group of non-designers, is there a graphic editing software that is specifically geared to creating stick figures like the one below?

**High level requirements (ideal)**

- A SaaS offering supporting multiple users and projects and the ability to administer these
- Preferably a freemium offering with the option to upgrade
- Support for iOS and Android including mobile devices and tablets
- Support for tagging
- The ability to search across the repository based on users, projects, tags, keywords, etc
- Reputable provider with a proven track record
- The ability to export or download in multiple formats such as SVG, PNG, JPG
- Support for vector images
- Library of templates, icons, stock imagery, etc
- Support for all major browsers and operating systems
- The ability to upload existing artwork for manipulation, editing, etc
- The ability to share, collaborate, etc with multiple users
- Integration with Google Drive, DropBox, etc

[image: example]